# Find network pcs connected on wan port

Tags: windows, networking, router, wan

If I connect the ethernet cable to my pc's lan port, on the network and sharing center all the discoverable pcs are listed. If I connect to my router wan port It only shows pcs on my lan. How to get all pcs connected on wan port network. FYI I'm using windows 8.1

Comment: You don't. The WAN port is usually the uplink to your modem/ISP - hence WAN. For network security you should really keep everything in the LAN!

Answer (score 0):

*all pcs connected on wan port network* = **all Internet**

Comment: No. There are some older ISP setups (mostly cable) where you are indeed sharing a MAC domain...